# how to get ref value of object table in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
create table mbastudent

(
semester  varchar2(20) ,

stud_info student
);
```

this is object table i have created

now iserting value--

```
insert into mbastudent

(semester,stud_info ) 

values 
('1st' ,student(1100 ,'KUMAR', '07-OCT-80', '04-MAR-14', 15000))

insert into mbastudent

(semester,stud_info ) 

values ('2nd',student(1101,'SESHU', '07-OCT-81', '04-MAR-14', 15000));
```

`select ref(a) from mbastudent a;`

--how to get ref value of object

Answer (score 0):

You may find it in 
[Oracle docs from site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-nov/o66plsql-088399.html)

I dont now structure of student. My sugesstion is

```
student (
id number,
name varchar2(4000),
birthday date,
begin_date date,
cost number
)
```

And you want to get a name, cost and semester

```
SELECT semester, stud_info.name, stud_info.cost
  FROM mbastudent s
```

Comment: Hi Michael ,i want to get  ref() value of student type object ,i want to use it as ref  data type in other table ,for example :                            CREATE TABLE StudentIncharges
(
 InchargeName VARCHAR2(30),
StudentIncharge REF STUDENT
);

Comment: Hi, what do you mean as ref datatype. If its just a sql-type to use for example insert as select. You may use just a `select  stud_info FROM mbastudent s`. that's query return stud_info as sql type. and you process it in PL SQL as `student` datatype for example. If I wring, could you please  provide why do you need a ref datatype and what do you mean when say ref datatype?